# My return statement in a fraction-simplifying function in Python doesn't work

Tags: python, function, return, user-defined-functions, fractions

I have this function that simplifies a fraction.

- Input: 2 numbers - a Numerator and a Denominator.
- Output: 2 numbers - a Numerator and a Denominator (simplified).

When I call the function to simplify `a = 12` and `b = 36`, and print them afterward, why are they still `a = 12` and `b = 36` and not `a = 1` and `b = 3`?

This Python code:

```
def simp(n, d):

  # Find the smaller number
  limit = min(n,d)

  # For loop that repeatedly divides numerator and denominator by a common dividend
  for dividend in range(limit, 2, -1):
    if (n % limit == 0) and (d % limit == 0):
      n = n / limit
      d = d / limit
  
  # Return the simplified numbers
  return (n, d)

a = 12
b = 36
print(a, "/", b,)
print("should be simplified down to")
simp(12, 36)
print(a, "/", b)
```

Outputs:

```
12 / 36
should be simplified down to
12 / 36
```

I don't think it is because of the algorithm, because when I tried `print(n, "/", d)` within the function, it correctly outputs `1 / 3`. So there is probably something wrong with the return statements, I just don't know what's wrong.

Comment: The return *does* work, you just ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `simp(12,36)` which returns a tuple but you don't assign it to anything.

all you need to do is where you call `simp` is put `[a,b] = simp(12,36)`

Edit:
Brackets are not needed, simply can be `a, b = simp(12,36)`. Thanks @Barmar

Comment: Prefer to use the variables: `a, b = simp(a, b)`

Answer (score 2):

You should have re-assigned the returned values to the variables a and b like this:

```
a, b = simp(a, b)
print(a, "/", b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you expect changes to the parameters (n,d) made inside the function to somehow alter the content of variables outside of it (a,b).  This is not the case so you must reassign the returned values to your original variables to update them: `a,b = simp(a,b)`

Rather than looping to find a common divisor, I would suggest using the gcd to get it directly.  It would make the function very simple.

```
# greatest common divisor (gcd using Euclidian division algorithm) 
def gcd(a,b): 
    return a if b == 0 else gcd(b,a%b) 

def simp(n, d):
    c = gcd(n,d)
    return (n//c,d//c)

print(*simp(12,36),sep="/")  # 1/3
```

Comment: I think the whole point of the exercise is to learn how to implement the algorithm, not just get the result.

Comment: If library is allowed, might as well do `from fractions import Fraction as simp` and then just `print(simp(12, 36))`.

Comment: @dtjc, right!  might as well go all the way if using libraries I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code, as is:

1. As other have mentioned, you don't capture the return values. You need `a,b = simp(a,b)`
2. You have two other bugs in the for loop, because you should be testing the remainder and dividing by `dividend` and, since range does not include the stop value, it should be 1 so that 2 is tested as a dividend.

```
  # For loop that repeatedly divides numerator and denominator by a common dividend
  for dividend in range(limit, 1, -1):
    if (n % dividend == 0) and (d % dividend == 0):
      n = n / dividend
      d = d / dividend
```

Lastly, this is not the best way to simplify a fraction, especially if the number are very large. You should compute the greatest common divisor, using [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) for example, and then numerator and denominator if >1.